# How can I get player's tag in spigot plugin 1.17

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

First I ran command in Minecraft

Minecraft Command Line> tag add AnPlayer Player

And I want to get AnPlayer's tag in plugin

Like this

```
Player p = Bukkit.getPlayer("AnPlayer");
Logger.getGlobal().info(p.getTags()[0].toString())
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I get player's tag?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happened when you tried that code?

Comment: Because the `Player.getTags()` method does not exist. See here: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html Did you try one of the other methods `getName()` or `getDisplayName()` or `getPlayerListName()`? As far as I know only objects/items can contain tags: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/persistence/PersistentDataHolder.html

Comment: So there is no way to get player's tag?

Comment: But how minecraft has /tag command?

Comment: Is it just created by microsoft?

Comment: I don't know for sure, it's been a long time since I have used spigot, but as per my second link, you might be looking for the `PersistentDataHolder`, which you should be able to get for a player using `PersistentDataContainer data = player.getPersistentDataContainer();` Then see here for more information about how to get/set the data: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/persistence/PersistentDataContainer.html